# How to protect my API service from api-keys piracy

Tags: security, api

I would like to roll my own REST API with a simple service. I would like to have three basic plans which will differ in terms of available req/sec.

Is there an easy way to prevent key switching? Let's say someone bought "enterprise" api-key and send it to others? Now others have access to "enterprise" level features without actually paying for this service.

Of course I will implement some kind of rate-limiting but that's not the point. I just want to make API available to people who actually purchased API-keys.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would only allowing one active connection per key be an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this using only API keys. You could try to do something like only accepting certain API keys from certain IP addresses, but there is a whole slew of issues with that. The only way to do this reliably is to force your clients to authenticate.

You can do this with username/password, where they need to send those to you to verify and you can check to see if that username has access to the plan/service. You can also do this with mutually-authenticated SSL where you issue self-signed client identity certificates to your clients and they use them to authenticate when they connect to your services and you can then do a lookup to see if that client has access to the plan/service. Note that you'd need to implement SSL in either case, as you don't want username/password going over standard HTTP.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!